# Notion-like editing and layout with a convenient freeform collaborative editor in WordPress?

Tags: block-editor, editor, visual-editor, post-editor, html-editor

I spend a lot of time developing technical content that revolves around software and network engineering. I used to do some content creation and blogging on this topic as well as creating documentation for clients, but I got tired of some of challenges of doing some of the more freeform things that I wanted to do and ended up rolling back over to traditional word processing.

A few months ago I discovered Notion and was floored by some of the opportunities to really create flexible documents that didn't fit within the normal realm of editing for the web. This has been really neat, but simultaneously I simply can't use their publishing platform for most of the work I do for various reasons.

Is there a Notion-like editing system (plugin) that allows both the Notion freeform style of document creation along with the accompanying collaboration for editors to collaborate on document creation in realtime for WordPress?

A huge bonus would also being able to do the editing in or with Markdown as well if desired.

I'd just love to bring the editing elements of Notion into content creation.

Comment: I would argue that [core Block Editor](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/) provides a very similar sort of modularized editing experience - and the next phase of the Gutenberg project is more or less entirely focused on live collaboration features. That said, please note that plugin recommendations are off-topic on this stack